# Conditional when calling functions sequentially in python

Tags: python, list, func

I have four functions and each one returns a list as a result. I want whichever of these functions that I call sequentially brings a list, not to look at the others. Thank you for your help.

```
def main(self):
    print(self.df_list)
    
    funcs = [(Calculate.free_two_kdv(self.df_list)),(Calculate.free_kdv(self.df_list)),(Calculate.zero_kdv(Calculate.find_largest_duplicated_value,self.df_list)),(Calculate.zero_with_other_kdv(Calculate.find_largest_duplicated_value,self.df_list))]
    for func in funcs:
        try:
            
            func()
            
        except ValueError:
            break
```

In short, I don't want it to go to other functions at all, whichever brings results.

Comment: You are not calling them inside the loop, you call them when you define the list. There is no enough information to suggest how you can refactor the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your functions immediately and storing the *result* in the list. Define a *new* function which makes the desired function call.

```
def main(self):
    print(self.df_list)
    
    funcs = [lambda: Calculate.free_two_kdv(self.df_list),
             lambda: Calculate.free_kdv(self.df_list),
             lambda: Calculate.zero_kdv(Calculate.find_largest_duplicated_value, self.df_list),
             lambda: Calculate.zero_with_other_kdv(Calculate.find_largest_duplicated_value, self.df_list)
    ]

    for func in funcs:
        try:
            return func()
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

It's not clear if you want `Calculate.find_largest_duplciated_value` as an *argument* to the first function, or if you want function composition (i.e., `f(g, x)` vs `f(g(x))`. If you want composition, it's

```
    funcs = [lambda: Calculate.free_two_kdv(self.df_list),
             lambda: Calculate.free_kdv(self.df_list),
             lambda: Calculate.zero_kdv(Calculate.find_largest_duplicated_value(self.df_list)),
             lambda: Calculate.zero_with_other_kdv(Calculate.find_largest_duplicated_value(self.df_list))
    ]
```

Comment: That's not what's written the original (though that might be what's intended).

Comment: You might be right, though; the original looks odd. I'm going to mention that (plus, what I have now isn't ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the func in funcs return either a list or None:

```
for func in funcs:
    if func(): break
```

```
for func in funcs:
    flist = func()
    if flist: break
```

The second receives the return value from the function for further work. try..except in this case has a greater performance cost than a straightforward boolean condition.